# How to change citation call-out style from superscript to numbers in square bracket?

Tags: citing, natbib

I am using NYU/Harvard PhD thesis template and I need to make some adjustments.
I need to change the citation call-outs to appear in square brackets instead of as superscripts.
For example :

I need this style: `[1-6]`.
Instead, I get superscript-type numbers, separated by commas (i.e., `1,2,5,6`)

Here is the link to the template :
https://github.com/suchow/Dissertate

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! This is the `numeric-comp` citation style for  `biblatex`.

Answer (score 1):

In the file `Dissertate.cls` of the thesis template package, you'll find the following instruction:

```
\RequirePackage[super,comma,numbers]{natbib}
```

Change it to

```
\RequirePackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mico, it worked but I still have one more question, the references are being inserted in alphabetic order instead of order that I insert them, how can I change that too? thanks.

Comment: @zizoojiloo - In `Dissertate.cls`, find the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apalike2}`. Replace it with, say, `\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}`.